# How to set value of Registry Key

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am having one Delphi XE2 project to write something in registry key. So I have defined the following codes :

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry: TRegistry;
begin
  RegistryEntry:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\')) then
  begin
    RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE;
    RegistryEntry.OpenKey('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\',True);
  end;
  RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  RegistryEntry.Free;
end;
```

If any string addition I have defined the following codes :

```
if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('Licenced To')) then
  begin
    RegistryEntry.WriteString('Licenced To', 'MySurname MyFirstName');
  end;
```

**My requirements :**

**01. Setting the default value as shown :[image: Picture]**

**02. In Win64 OS the node is created under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WOWSys64\Software but not under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software.**

Comment: The default value is named `''` (that is, the empty string).

Comment: That's the registry redirector doing its thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx If your program is a 32 bit app then perhaps you should let it do its thing

Comment: But hot set **MyFirstProject** string?

Comment: I think it can be possible only using **RegSetValueEx**.

Comment: @RubiHalder: I told you so in my comment. `WriteString('', 'MySecondProject')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is working properly.

Comment: I have check the value. If the **Deafault Value is not MySecondProject** then only the value be set. It may be Binary or Hex.

Comment: For reading the **Default Value** I have defined the following          if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\')) then
        Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.readstring('(Default)'));
        //or Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.readstring(''));
        //or Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.readstring('@'));        But none is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that desired behavoir for 32-Bit applications.
If you need to write to 64-Bit root you can use KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
In any case you will need elevated rights for writung to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

```
RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
```

Comment: @Rubi However, since your app is a 32 bit app, perhaps you should let the redirector do its job.

Comment: No. No. My requirement is to write under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software** in Win64 OS not under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node**. Please help.

Comment: What on earth do you mean "Please help"?! @bummi has already told you how to do it! I have a feeling that you don't know what the registry redirector is. Read the link in my comment to the question. Do be aware that your 32 bit programs will always read from the 32 bit view unless you force the issue using `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. So if your programs want to read back that key, they will always need to use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.

Comment: @WarrenP (facepalm) for me?

Comment: No the OP. You've given him good advice on how to do something that still might be a BAD idea for his exact case. He may not understand what Wow64 reg redirection is all about, as David says.  People here just ask for "How to do?" and seem not to care if it's a good idea or not.