# How to read Default Value of Registry Key

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 project to work something with registry key. So I have defined the following codes :

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry: TRegistry;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\')) then
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      RegistryEntry.OpenKey('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\',True);
      RegistryEntry.WriteString('', 'MyFirstProject');
    end
  else
    begin
      Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.ReadString('(Default)')); //Not Working
      Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.ReadString('')); //Not Working
      Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.ReadString('@')); //Not Working
    end;
  RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  RegistryEntry.Free;
end;
```

My requirement is to check the Default Value of "MyName" and to show in Memo01. But nothing is heppening. So I have tried another way as follows :

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry: TRegistry;
  RegistryString: string;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\')) then
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      RegistryEntry.OpenKey('Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\',True);
      RegistryEntry.WriteString('', 'MyFirstProject');
    end
  else
    begin
      RegistryString := RegistryEntry.ReadString('(Default)'); //Not Working
      RegistryString := RegistryEntry.ReadString(''); //Not Working
      RegistryString := RegistryEntry.ReadString('@'); //Not Working
      Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryString);
    end;
  RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  RegistryEntry.Free;
end;
```

But it is also not working.

Comment: Q: Have you tried RegQueryValueEx('')?  An empty string (`''`) should be all you need.  Q: Are you sure this particular key *has* a default value?  Can you see it in RegEdit?

Comment: No no. I have not tried RegQueryValueEx. Yes everything is regarding the **Default Value**.

Comment: But, @Rubi, I told you this [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144046/how-to-set-value-of-registry-key#comment23064639_16144046). Twice.

Comment: What sort of program do you have that feels the need to claim elevated rights every time it runs, just so that it can write to HKLM the first time it runs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no Openkey in your else part.

```
Const
  C_KEY='Software\MyCompanyName\MyName\';
var
  RegistryEntry: TRegistry;
  RegistryString: string;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  try
    RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists(C_KEY)) then
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access := KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      if RegistryEntry.OpenKey(C_KEY, true) then
        RegistryEntry.WriteString('', 'MyFirstProject');
    end
    else
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access := KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      if RegistryEntry.OpenKey(C_KEY, false) then
      begin
        Memo01.Lines.Add(RegistryEntry.ReadString(''));
      end;
    end;
    RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  finally
    RegistryEntry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Make sure you check the return value of `OpenKey()` for failure before calling `ReadString()` or `WriteString()`, or else they can raise exceptions if the key is not opened.

Comment: Indeed, the standard idiom is `if OpenKey... then`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

In Vista/7/8, unless the program is run using administrator rights, you don't actually get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, you get a virtualized location. Essentially, Windows gives you something only that user can see.

Using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE only leads to headaches later on. Windows has been locking that down.