# Where is the Component Toolbar configuration data stored in Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to customize the appearance of the Component Toolbar pages within Delphi XE4. I clicked on Tools > Options > Component Toolbar

I highlighted Data Access and moved it up underneath Standard and clicked OK. However it still shows up in the IDE Tool Palette in the original location underneath Samples.

[image]

[image]

Ray Konopka distributes a utility that moves all the Raize components to the top of the list in the Tool Palette so there's got to be a config file somewhere that I can tweek so the pages and components are in the order I'd like them to be.

Where can I find this file?

Comment: I move the categories by drag'n'drop direct inside the tool palette. Or do you want to build a tool for that?

Comment: My frustration came when I discovered the Move-up/Move-down function from within the Tool>Options... didn't work. I know I can drag and drop but there must be a config file because you can right click and Reset Palette. At this point it is more a curiosity thing.

Comment: The configuration is generally stored in registry. [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) should guide you where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Delphi XE, it is stored in the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\ToolForm\Mapping(Default), so I guess that for Delphi XE4, it will be HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\11.0\ToolForm\Mapping(Default). To read this key, this answer should help : [How to read Default Value of Registry Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176847/781542)